# How do I extract the pre-master secret using an OpenSSL-based client?

Tags: c, ssl, openssl, wireshark

I have an application I'm making that uses OpenSSL 1.0.2 and I'd like to examine the traffic with Wireshark. Wireshark can (allegedly) decrypt TLS conversations provided you give it the pre-master secret.

If I'm using a cipher suite like `TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA256`; can anyone tell me how to get the pre-master secret out of an `SSL` or `SSL_CTX` struct? I'm OK with hacking opaque structures within the `SSL` object - this isn't for anything that would ship in a product; I just want to know how to populate a pre-master secret file for Wireshark.

Comment: Also see [Extract pre-master keys from an OpenSSL application](http://security.stackexchange.com/q/80158/29925) on InfoSec.SE.

Comment: Its probably noteworthy now that OpenSSL 1.1.0 has been released: many structures have been made opaque, so you will probably have to do a fair amount of hacking.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I recommend using the master key, which is easier to get at. To the best of my knowledge the pre-master key only exists ephemerally on the stack in OpenSSL. The master key is available in [`ssl_session_st`](https://github.com/openssl/openssl/blob/OpenSSL_1_0_2-stable/ssl/ssl.h#L505) (defined in `ssl.h` in the 1.0.2 branch but moved to `ssl_locl.h` in a later version). The `SSL` member variable `session` is a pointer to its `ssl_session_st` (aka `SSL_SESSION`).

Wireshark can use the master key as well as the pre-master key to decrypt connections. [Here are the formats](https://code.wireshark.org/review/gitweb?p=wireshark.git;a=blob;f=epan/dissectors/packet-ssl-utils.c;h=ac77c8203ceae52d3d0dce56be6a12340a8de1c2;hb=HEAD#l4695) that Wireshark supports as of this writing:

- `RSA xxxx yyyy`
  Where `xxxx` are the first 8 bytes of the encrypted pre-master secret (hex-encoded)
  Where `yyyy` is the cleartext pre-master secret (hex-encoded)
  (this is the original format introduced with bug 4349)
- `RSA Session-ID:xxxx Master-Key:yyyy`
  Where `xxxx` is the SSL session ID (hex-encoded)
  Where `yyyy` is the cleartext master secret (hex-encoded)
  (added to support openssl s_client Master-Key output)
  This is somewhat is a misnomer because there's nothing RSA specific
  about this.
- `PMS_CLIENT_RANDOM xxxx yyyy`
  Where `xxxx` is the client_random from the ClientHello (hex-encoded)
  Where `yyyy` is the cleartext pre-master secret (hex-encoded)
  (This format allows SSL connections to be decrypted, if a user can
  capture the PMS but could not recover the MS for a specific session
  with a SSL Server.)
- `CLIENT_RANDOM xxxx yyyy`
  Where `xxxx` is the client_random from the ClientHello (hex-encoded)
  Where `yyyy` is the cleartext master secret (hex-encoded)
  (This format allows non-RSA SSL connections to be decrypted, i.e.
  ECDHE-RSA.)

Note that neither the pre-master key nor the master key is the symmetric key (your question title implies that you may think it is). The symmetric key is derived from the master key and client/server random data.

Comment: rhashimoto: Yes! This is exactly the information I needed. And you're right - I was confused - I thought that the pre-master secret was the symmetric key. I'm going to amend the title to better reflect this to avoid confusing anyone.

Comment: FYI: OpenSSL 1.1.0 provides [SSL_SESSION_get_master_key()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.0/ssl/SSL_SESSION_get_master_key.html) function.

Comment: Previous link doesn't work, here is the new one:
[SSL_SESSION_get_master_key()](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/SSL_SESSION_get_master_key.html)