# Members of SSL structure

Tags: c, ssl, openssl

In a OpenSSL's SSL/TLS client [implementation](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/SSL/TLS_Client), a structure `SSL` is defined. For example here is usually the first few lines (from the link).

```
SSL_CTX* ctx = NULL;
BIO *web = NULL, *out = NULL;
SSL *ssl = NULL;

init_openssl_library();
```

I have been unable to find its structure in the header files from the OpenSSL library. How can I learn the contents of `SSL * ssl`?

Comment: It's an opaque structure, the application doesn't need to know the contents.

Comment: Whatever reason you think you have to know its contents: you don't. If you're curious or want to aid in the development: read the source code.

Comment: Just like you don't need to know the structure of `FILE` when you use `stdio`.

Comment: I am just curious for now and I cannot find its definition in the header files (https://github.com/openssl/openssl). I have checked openssl/include/openssl/ssl.h and a bunch of other files. Basically I want to know which structure holds the keys generated at the end of a handshake.

Comment: @Olaf - *"Whatever reason you think you have to know its contents: you don't"* - there's lots of reasons one may want to see the contents. I can think of a handful without trying, like logging and offline analysis of a session. Other reasons include studying and tracing the source to solve a problem because of missing documentation.

Comment: @steffen did point to the right answer and like I mentioned I did go through that file but I missed it. As of my understanding by going through the other files as well, there is no structure to hold the keys generated after the handshake (there is a structure for master secret but not for the read/write encryption and mac keys.

Comment: @Choi - Yes, Steffen is well versed in OpenSSL. Folks like SU know how OpenSSL typedef's structures and hides implementations. Regarding *"keys generated after the handshake"*... In the past, you wanted/needed access to either the premaster secret or the master secret. From there, you could get the 4 sessions keys (SSLv2) or 6 sessions keys (SSLv3 and above). Also see questions like [How do I extract the pre-master secret using an OpenSSL-based client?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/36240279)

Comment: @jww: I clearly covered valid reasons, e.g. work on the sources themselves. I don't see a problem with the opaque `struct` for users of this lib here. For debugging the lib, use the debug versions and should have all information available. Logging like any other application code should not rely on intternal data which can change anytime without notice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have been unable to find its structure type in the header files from the openssl library.

It's unclear which version of openssl you are referring too and how did you look but a `grep -r ' SSL;' /usr/include/openssl/` quickly turned up a match in openssl/ossl_typ.h for openssl 1.0.2:

```
   typedef struct ssl_st SSL;
```

A following grep for 'ssl_st' lead to its definition in openssl/ssl.h:

```
#ifndef OPENSSL_NO_SSL_INTERN

struct ssl_st
        {
        /* protocol version
         * (one of SSL2_VERSION, SSL3_VERSION, TLS1_VERSION, DTLS1_VERSION)
         */
        int version;
        int type; /* SSL_ST_CONNECT or SSL_ST_ACCEPT */
...
```

Note that location and content of the structure might differ in other versions of openssl.

Comment: I somehow miss a clear warning not to use this `struct` in the user code. Typically there is a good reason to hide implementation details of a `struct` from the application code.

Comment: @Olaf: first these are header files installed during the openssl installation, so the information are not that hidden from the application. Then I wrote: "Note that location and content of the structure might differ in other versions of openssl.". Apart from that - depending on the version of OpenSSL several internals which are needed by code are only reachable by using undocumented functions or reaching into the internals. They've changed a lot with 1.1.0 by both making internals less visible and publishing stable API's for things previously only offered by reaching into the internals.

Comment: "depending on the version of OpenSSL several internals which are needed by code are only reachable by using undocumented functions or reaching into the internals." - Ok, that's the only valid reason. It is a design-flaw in the lib, though and against common practice.

Comment: @Olaf: of course, if there is an API suitable to solve the specific problem one should always use it instead of reaching into the internals. Otherwise code maintenance would be a nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

In openssl 1.1.1 `ssl_st` is defined in /ssl/ssl_local.h, line 1080.

For some reason this seems to be a hidden definition, even though some callback require this structure as an argument.